# "What score are we playing until?" or how to ask it?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-order

Every day Jack and Ted have about 5–15 minutes to go outside and play table tennis in the afternoon. As their free time varies each time (sometimes it's 5 minutes, sometimes 10, sometimes 15), they always agree before the game about how long their game is going to be. Though it's the time that is really limiting them, they still prefer to take their scoring in the game as their limiting factor (it's not a big problem for them if they finish one or two minutes before or after their free time is over). So, each time before the game Jack usually asks Ted,

1. "What score are we playing until?"
2. "Until what score are we playing?"
3. "What score are we playing till?"
4. "Till what score are we playing?"
5. "What score will we play until?"
6. "Until what score will we play?"
7. "What score will we play till?"
8. "Till what score will we play?"
9. or... What question would you ask in this situation?

Comment: If you really want to list all possible permutations, you should have a set using **'til** (occurs everywhere, I think, but particularly in US).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *'til* is just a misspelling of *till* based on the incorrect assumption that it's younger than *until*. Make it go away, I say.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I think *misspelling* is a little harsh. It's slowly working its way up from 'informal' to 'standard'. That whiff of informality, plus those who think it's just a misspelling, are all that's holding this great word back. It saves all the bother of worrying whether you should use *until* or *till*  - which are effectively different words, despite having common ancestry. Anyway, *'til* has always been around, and I don't think it's gonna go away. And I for one shan't mind if it does take over.

Comment: @brilliant: If Jack & Ted do this every day, pretty soon they'd just do the original negotiation over game duration in score points, rather than minutes (sorry - I know it's just a sample scenario).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "*soon they'd just do the original negotiation over game duration in score points, rather than minutes*" - I don't understand what you are talking about. In my example they DO negotiate the game duration in score points every time. They don't negotiate minutes - how much free time they have each time is not up to them, so they can't negotiate the time. Plus, the free time they enjoy each time is different.

Comment: @brilliant: Oh I see. I thought your scenario meant *they* decided how many minutes to spare for the game, then converted that to points. In you scenario, maybe they could ask the boss to define their time off in points rather than minutes. But I guess he'd refuse, worried they might just play long slow rallies all afternoon.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What? We agree. Re-read what I wrote. *'Til* should be spelled *till*, because *until* is derived from *till*, and not the other way around. If you want to spell it *til*, with just the one L, then that's another matter; the apostrophe, however, is sheer silly hypercorrection.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I don't disagree with your history lesson. But *till* and the later *until* are now two different words with much the same meaning and usage. Most people who put the apostrophe in *'til* assume it just elides the *un-*. It doesn't matter that they *could* have meant to write *till* in the first place, because mostly they didn't. Anyway, I'm not much of one for laying down the law about *how* people should write - I'm more interested in seeing what they actually *do*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm in the descriptivist camp myself, which is why instances of hypercorrection (or at least what I perceive to be such) do irk me a bit: it implies application of an *artificial* rule, which may or may not have any factual basis.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Nah - I still don't get it. It's perfectly reasonable to elide the *un-* both in speech and (informal) writing. The possibility that any given writer *might* have intended *till* but got the orthography wrong doesn't mean we're all doing it out of ignorance. Oftentimes, grammatical rules don't *define* valid forms - they're just later rationalisations for what people were actually doing. If people had happened to do things differently, we'd just classify into different rules.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm just saying that it's a bit silly. Writing *'til* as though it's derived from *until* makes exactly as little sense as writing *'to* as though it's derived from *into*.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: OK well I don't deny you're technically correct. I'm just saying that - silly or not - it's what people *do*, so we have to get used to it. Perhaps if you'd been around at the right time you'd have persuaded people to eat *a norange* instead of *an orange*. But it's definitely too late for that one, and I suspect it's too late for this one too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In America we'd most likely just say:

> Play to 21?

or

> We playing to 21?

Or substitute a number of your own, depending on the game.

Answer (score 2):

How about: "What's the target score?"

Comment: "*How about: "What's the target score?"*" - Are you asking me? If I knew the answer I wouldn't post this question here :) Your suggestion, however, sparked another idea in me: "What's the final score?". What do you think? Or, perhaps, this question would suit better for a game that has already finished.

Comment: I was asking what you think about that phrasing, since I can not recall a commonly used phrase and that seems right. "Final score" is more suitable for a completed game, as "latest score" is suitable for a game in progress.

Comment: "*I was asking what you think about that phrasing, since I can not recall a commonly used phrase and that seems right*" - Well, I like your phrasing and to me it sounds nice, but since I am not an English speaker, I may be wrong. Anyway, thank you for this suggestion and for the explanations on "final score".

Answer (score 1):

"What score are we playing to?" should be very easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered, usually "best n out of 2n-1" is used,
where n is a natural number.

Comment: Please, give me example with a number, otherwise I don't understand. Also, would that be used as a question in that situation described above?

Comment: Best 2 out of 3, 3 out of 5, 10 out of 19. It can be used as a declaration or as a suggestion.